# html2canvas screenshot an image

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I have found this code that takes a screenshot of a form. I am trying to take a screenshot of an image or a video.
Is there a way that can take a screenshot of a part of the webpage and saves it the way this code is saving the form ?

This is my html code

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <head>
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  <title>Poster</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var Submit = function() {
  html2canvas(document.body, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    }
   });
   };
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="main_image">
   <img src="image.jpg" id= "image"/>
   <div id="user_text">IT IS TOTALLY AWESOME</div>
    </div>
   <div id="edit_text_box">
   <textarea id="user_input" placeholder="Your text here.." rows="2" cols="30" >   </textarea>
   <div id="change_size">
    <span style="float: left;">FONT-SIZE : </span>
   <button id="decrease_size">-</button>
   <button id="increase_size">+</button>
   </div>
   <button onclick="Submit();" >Submit</button>
   </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/edit_text.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: You basically want to put an image or video inside a canvas? http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/

Comment: @JonasGrumann Actually I am trying to take a screenshot of an image instead of a form

Comment: Why would you take a screenshot of an image? Why not use the image itself? Can you give more information about the context and the desired output?

Comment: @JonasGrumann suure I have a video that is playing and being edited I am trying to take a screenshot with specific width and height of that video after edits. and then I want to save this screenshot. Once the video is paused its basically taking a screenshot of an image.

Comment: How do you edit the video? Using flash? I think editing a video would only be possible with flash or canvas, or are you just adding html elements to it?

Comment: am using canvas to edit the videos
I am drawing on the them and I need to take a screenshot of what I drew

Answer (score 0):

To take the actual image from a canvas and copy it on another one you need to take all the imageData of the first canvas (the one with the edited video)

```
var myImageData = context.getImageData(left, top, width, height);
```

and put the imageData on the second canvas:

```
targetContext.putImageData(myImageData, dx, dy);
```

and to save it as an image:

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL();
```

After that you will have a string as image that can be used as the src attribute for html images.

Note that you're asking how to copy something onto a canvas that why I told you about the getImageData and putImageData. If you only need the image of the current status of the original image, you don't need the first step, just use canvas.toDataURL